# How to disable flask's Auto Reloading?

Tags: python, flask

I am running a `flask` server on my machine. I want to stop `flask` from auto reloading once a code is changed.
I am running app as=>

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Commands I am using =>

```
set FLASK_APP=my_application
flask run
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: app.run(use_reloader=False)

Answer (score 6):

By passing the `-no-reload` option to `flask run`

```
flask run --no-reload
```

Check the docs [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/server/)